# Pytube issues with some links

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, pytube

there is a problem when i use pytube:

some links doesn;t work like this one    https://youtu.be/7R-cDQ8VoM0   and i dont know why can anyone help ? this is my code:

```
def DownloadVideo():
        try:
            ytlink = link.get()
            YtObject = YouTube(ytlink , on_progress_callback= on_progressAudio)
            stream = YtObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            stream.download(output_path= fd.askdirectory(), filename = f"{YtObject.title}.mp4" )
            CTkMessagebox(title  = "Done", icon = "info", message ="Download Completed ✅")
            window2.destroy()
        except:
            CTkMessagebox(title  = "invalid link", icon = "cancel", message ="Please enter a correct link !")
```

i tried copying the same link from other tabs but the same issue happen

[an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULGxT.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be easier to help you if you tell us what *does* happen (an error message?), what you *expect* to happen, and make sure your code can be copied, pasted, and run on its own, generating the same problem. This is called a [mre].

Comment: It is better to print out the exception to console for debugging.  Currently you don't know what is wrong when exception is raised.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue using your code with hardcoded output directory and filename.